# Reset BehaviorSubject from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've made a facade service to avoid multiple calls to the API.

It call `retrieveMyUser` each time the request is made.

If the request has never been made it store the value using`BehaviorSubject`. If it has already been made it take the value stored.

I want to clear the data of my `BehaviorSubject` in **auth.service.ts** when a user logout. My try to do that is that I call a `clearUser()` method from **facade-service.ts**.

**facade-service.ts** :

```
... 

export class UserServiceFacade extends UserService {
  public readonly user = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  retrieveMyUser() {
    console.log(this.user.value); 
    return this.user.pipe(
      startWith(this.user.value),
      switchMap(user => (user ? of(user) : this.getUserFromServer())),
      take(1)
    )
  }

  private getUserFromServer() {
    return super.retrieveMyUser(null, environment.liveMode).pipe(tap(user => this.storeUser(user)));
  }

  public clearUser() {
    console.log("cleared");
    this.storeUser(null)
    console.log(this.user.value); // Output null
  }

  private storeUser(user: V2UserOutput) {
    this.user.next(user);
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts** :

```
... 

  logout() {
    var cognitoUser = this.userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser) {
      this.userServiceFacade.clearUser()
      cognitoUser.signOut();
    }
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
...
```

The method `clearUser()` in **auth.service.ts** is well called and print *cleared* correctly.

But when I login, after I logout the `console.log(this.user.value);` in `retrieveMyUser` still output the previous value. It was `null` when at logout though.

So, how do I clear BehaviorSubject cache or to reset BehaviorSubject from another service ?

Comment: Use `this.user.getValue()` instead

Comment: Try removing `readonly` on `user = new BehaviorSubject(null);`

Comment: You should try removing ```take(1)```.

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one instance of UserServiceFacade?

Comment: Thanks but all your solution do not work. @LukaszGawrys if I remove it all break down since the value will stay null. But like you I think the problem come from what is inside my pipe()

Answer (score 0):

There are many things in your code which sound weird at reading:

- You shouldn't access immediately to the value of a BehaviorSubject without using the asObservable() as recommended by ESLint [here](https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs/blob/main/docs/rules/no-subject-value.md).
- Instead, you could use another variable which will keep the latest value for the user.
- You should use the power of TypeScript in order to help you with types definition and quality code (in my opinion).
- The use of a BehaviorSubject with a startWith operator can be simplified using a [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) with a bufferSize of 1 (replay the latest change)
- Your subject acting like a source storage should be private in order to limit the accessibility from outside.

I took your code and make some updates from what I said above:

```
export class UserServiceFacade extends UserService {

    private _user: V2UserOutput;
    private readonly _userSource = new ReplaySubject<V2UserOutput>(1);

    public get user(): V2UserOutput { // Use for accessing to the user data without the use of an observable.
        return this._user;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.clearUser(); // It will make your ReplaySubject as "alive".
    }

    public retrieveMyUser$(): Observable<V2UserOutput> {
        return this._userSource.asObservable()
            .pipe(
                switchMap(user => (user ? of(user) : this.getUserFromServer())),
                take(1)
            );
    }

    private getUserFromServer(): Observable<V2UserOutput> {
        return super.retrieveMyUser(null, 'environment.liveMode')
            .pipe(
                tap(user => this.storeUser(user))
            );
    }

    public clearUser() {
        console.log('cleared');
        this.storeUser(null);
    }

    private storeUser(user: V2UserOutput) {
        this._user = user;

        this._userSource.next(user);
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: My super() gets arguments, so I've tried your solution with super(null, null, null) which leave me with an error. Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null. But anyway I don't see the point on how this would fix my problem, but you're right my cause is not perfect regarding the norm. Thanks though

Comment: @crg Maybe you could share your UserService code and I'll try my best for helping you. FYI, the code that I gave you works from my side.